# What search engine does Stack Overflow use and why?

Tags: discussion, search

When it comes to the search bar at the top of Stack Overflow website, what kind of search engine do they use to bring the right result? and I am also wondering why they chose to use that search engine.

Comment: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/165483) and [How does Stack Overflow implement its search indexing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187431/165483)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what kind of search engine do they use to bring the right result

They use https://www.elastic.co/.

> why they chose to use that search engine

It was chosen based on perceived performance and the ability to customize search parameters.

---

Maybe in 2013 that made sense.

Going forward, it would be nice if search were a bigger focus at some point. In my opinion, there is a lot to be desired with regards to search at Stack Overflow both in terms of the internal search as well as the way that Stack Overflow presents itself to Google (and other engines).

Comment: I wonder what would make more sense today, I'd probably still choose for Elastic to be honest.